# Is there an equivalent of numpy.gradient for R?

Tags: python, r, numpy

I have found several gradient functions associated with various R packages, but they all ask for a function to be passed as an argument in addition to the vector of values. Are there any that do the same thing as numpy.gradient if e.g. I just passed an identity function or something like that?

For all intents and purposes, this example on the numpy.gradient page exemplifies what I'm looking for: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html

```py
f = np.array([1, 2, 4, 7, 11, 16], dtype=float)
np.gradient(f)
array([1. , 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5. ])
```

I am looking for the same algorithm in an R package.

Comment: can you share the python code and expected output?

Comment: edited to include the example from the numpy.gradient documentation which is the same thing I'm looking for. input a vector in R, get a calculated gradient output of the same length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a package called `pracma` in R that would do this for you. Let me know if this works for you.

```
install.packages('pracma')
library(pracma)

x <- c(1, 2, 4, 7, 11, 16)

pracma::gradient(x)
```

> [1] 1.0 1.5 2.5 3.5 4.5 5.0